# Some of the shapefile layer points still are outside of boundary even after correcting latitude and longitude

Tags: qgis, shapefile, overlay

I have two shapefiles, one points and the other one polygons. These two layers should overlay without any points being outside of boundary. Unfortunately, there were some points that were outside and the reason was that the points had incorrect latitude and longitude. I replaced them with correct latitude and longitude, however the points are still outside of boundary. I also changed Coordinate System to have the two layers use the same one (not sure if I did in right way). Even after changing the coordinate, I still have the problem. Below is a screenshot.

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

Comment: can you post the files or show us at least the complete error-message (your screenshot only shows a part of the error-mwssage: Invalid Data source.....)

Comment: 1. Don't ever set the CRS of a layer, unless it is really wrong. QGIS is capable of on-the-fly reprojection, overlaying layers as they should be. 2. How did you replace the faulty coordinates?

Comment: How did you "replaced them with correct latitude and longitude"? Modifying the attribute table will not help. You need to change the location of the geometry.

Comment: @Kurt, The error-message is for a different file that I attempted to add. For the two files that the screenshot displays, it doesn't give me any error. I successfully add them.

Comment: @Erik, I just added the layers again and this time I DID NOT change the CRS. I changed the coordinated through attribute table.

Comment: @HekkiVesanto - Great to know. I did it through attribute table.How can I change the location of the geometry? Do I need to unchanged the changes I made to the attribute table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Vertex Tool to move a point by directly editing it's geometry values.

Put your layer in edit mode and activate the Vertex Tool:

[image]

You will now see the Vertex Editor panel widget docked on the left of the map canvas.

[image]

Now, when you right-click on a point you can edit the feature geometry's x and y values to move the point to a specific location.

[image]

Comment: For single part point layers, this works well. For all other types of lyers (multipart points, lines, polygons), this changes the geometry (shape). This can be tricky if you're not aware of it. Move features moves the whole feature. In case of single part points, each feature consists of just one vertex, so then it makes no difference.

Comment: you do not have a nice profile picture anymore 

Comment: @Taras, sorry! I'm just going incognito for a little while ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To move points, toggle edit mode, then select the [Move feature(s)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#move-feature-s) tool.

[image]

Now you can manually shift the points: with the activated tool, left click on a point, release move the point and when it is in the right location once again left click. The point will be placed there.

If Move features is not visible, activate `Advanced Digitizin Toolbar` from `Menu View / Toolbars`.

Comment: Thank you @Babel. Does it allow me to move it to a specific lat/lon?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can see at the bottom in the coordinates field the coordinates.

Comment: @ Babel Sounds great. Thanks.